# Future dependent actions - verb tense

Tags: verbs

Does Italian use the Simple Future tense for future events on which some other event depends on? Examples:

- Parlerà quando potrà. (Verb in question: potere)
- Parlerà appena finirà di mangiare. (Verb in question: finire)

My question arises from the fact that Portuguese, Spanish and French use distinct verb tenses for such a situation.

Comment: Can you give an example in French (and maybe Portuguese and Spanish, but French is easier for me)? The tense systems of French and Italian are pretty much identical, and I am not exactly sure what you're referring to (maybe the *futuro anteriore*?)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Spanish uses subjunctive in these situations:  "Hablará cuando pueda" and "Hablará cuando haya acabado de comer".

Comment: @DenisNardin: Spanish uses subjunctive present in both sentences, as already mentioned. Portuguese uses subjunctive future in both sentences: "Ele falará quando puder" and "Ele falará quando tiver acabado". French uses "futur simple" and "futur anterieur": "Il parlera quand il pourra" and "Il parlera dès qu'il aura fini de manger". I was not sure if Italian was equal to one of those Romance languages in this matter, but your comment made it clear.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Yes, Italian works pretty much like French (up to a few Gallicismes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Parlerà quando potrà.*

The action *potere* is simultaneous to the action *parlare*, so we use the *futuro semplice* for both verbs.

> *Parlerà appena avrà finito di mangiare.*

The action *finire (di mangiare)* precedes the action *parlare*, so we use the *futuro anteriore* for the verb describing the earlier action.